# PHP Custom Error Handler: How to determine if exception was generated within try{}catch{} block?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I have a custom error handlers:

```
set_error_handler('API_Error_Handler');
register_shutdown_function('Fatal_Error_Handler'); // This one calls API_Error_Handler eventually
```

In the following example, both `catch{}` section AND `API_Error_Handler` are executed.

```
try{
  // Exception raised here
} catch(Exception $e){
  // No error reporting needed, do something else
}
```

I want ONLY `catch{}` to execute. How do I do that? Maybe determine within `API_Error_Handler` whether exception is already caught by try-catch? Or are there other approaches available?

Example code:

```
set_error_handler(function() {
  echo "Error is handled by custom error handler. <br>"; 
});

try{
  new SoapClient('http://bad.address/wsdl');
} catch(Exception $e){
  echo "Error is caught. <br>";
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) about the `set_error_handler` function?

Comment: Keep in mind you registered both an error handler and a shut down function. The latter will always be called.

Comment: What do you mean? The error handler [should not execute](http://3v4l.org/Xk9A9) if the exception is caught. There's no need to call the error handler in the shutdown function if there was no error. You can for presence of error with `error_get_last()`.

Comment: @Anonymous Well it does execute. I've added example code to the description. Try running it on http://phptester.net (it has Soap extension enabled, so you get the same types as I do)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to create an Exception class by your self that extends Exception:

```
class MyCustomException extends \Exception {}
```

and throw this where you need it. Then change

```
} catch (Exception $e)
```

to

```
} catch (MyCustomException $e)
```

and you should only get your custom exception catched

Comment: Will this work for exceptions generated by PHP plug-ins, like SoapClient? Because it's throwing 1 Error and 3 Warnings at the line `new SoapClient('http://bad.address/wsdl');`. Each of them executes `API_Error_Handler` separately.